# "Formal derivative $S[x]\to S[x]$ is nothing but the map obtained by extending scalars"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am looking at lemma 9.9 in [this document](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jmckerna/Teaching/16-17/Winter/200B/l_9.pdf). It states:

> The formal derivative is an $R$-linear map (considering $R[x]$ as a
>   module over $R$ by restriction of scalars) which satisfies
>   $D(fg)=(Df)g+f(Dg)$. Further if we are given a ring homomorphism
>   $\phi:R\to S$, then the formal derivative $S[x]\to S[x]$ is nothing but
>   the map obtained by extending scalars.

Linearity and the product rule is all well and good, but what is meant by the statement about extension of scalars? If we have $R[x]$ an $R$-module, then $S$ is an $R$-module (by $r\cdot s=\phi(r)s$), and so $R[x]\otimes S$ is an $S$-module. But I don't see how the formal derivative or even $S[x]$ plays into this. Maybe "extending scalars" doesn't mean "extension of scalars", but I don't see what else it could mean.

Answer (score 1):

If $f : M \to N$ is a morphism of $R$-modules, it induces a map

$$S \otimes_R f : S \otimes_R N \to S \otimes_R M$$

by the functoriality of extension of scalars. The formal derivative is a morphism $R[x] \to R[x]$ of $R$-modules, so it defines by extension of scalars a morphism $S[x] \to S[x]$ of $S$-modules, which is the formal derivative on $S[x]$.

Comment: Via an isomorphism $S\otimes_R R[x]\cong S[x]$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.